# Problem in Reloading UITableview..!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

i am parsing two xml files with one xml parser class , i have a table view where the data is displaying after parsing .. here is a imageview and label , when i parse the first xml like if i parse `myxml_1.xml` and then display data in a table view its fine . but when i parse again the xml named `myxml_2.xml` and display the data in that table view its displaying uilabel fine but the image is not displaying properly it always display the images that i have in my first xml ..

i have used mytableview.reloadData...but Still have a problem .
here is a code placed in cellforrowatindexpath ..

```
///its a label///
labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(12, 0, 300, 44)]; 
  [labelView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
  //[labelView setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
  [labelView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0]]; 
  [labelView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [labelView setTag:223]; 
  [cell addSubview:labelView]; 
  [labelView release]; 
///working fine ///

///this is for imageview////
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:newimage];
  NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
  [cell.imageView setImage:image];
///Not Working ///
```

Your help will be appreciated..!
Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind explaining it a little more clearly? Ie: separating the code and formatting it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One big problem with what you are showing here is that you are loading data synchronously inside a cellForRow:atIndexPath: method of UITableViewController.  That method gets called every time a tableview is created to show on the screen.  If a user is scrolling your view up and down, the method gets called every time a cell leaves and comes back on screen.

To try to narrow dow the problem you have mentioned, I would first try to nil out the old image, and then assert that there is actually data in the new one before you set it.